# setpgid: Operation not permitted on Docker

Tags: docker, cron, alpine-linux

Any ideas why the following works (the Docker container runs without errors):

```
FROM alpine:3.14.0

RUN apk update && \
    apk --no-cache add dcron

COPY entry.sh /entry.sh
RUN chmod +x /entry.sh

CMD /entry.sh
```

```
# entry.sh
#!/bin/sh

# start cron
/usr/sbin/crond -f
```

While the following

```
FROM alpine:3.14.0

RUN apk update && \
    apk --no-cache add dcron

CMD /usr/sbin/crond -f
```

gives me the

```
cnt  | setpgid: Operation not permitted
cnt exited with code 1
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I think that is related to `alpine:3.14.0`.
Check it out:

- https://gitlab.alpinelinux.org/alpine/aports/-/issues/12396
- https://wiki.alpinelinux.org/wiki/Release_Notes_for_Alpine_3.14.0#faccessat2

Try to update you Docker version

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it has something with how Linux process group ID and session ID works (more details in [credentials(7)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/credentials.7.html)) and should be fixed in dcron.

At the moment [dcron calls setpgid if started with `-f` option](https://github.com/dubiousjim/dcron/blob/1ba33c3325df48de46263276a43ed76cf9d81518/main.c#L269-L275):

- If dcron is started as PID1 in container - it works.
- If dcron is started as non-PID1 in container - it also works.
- But if some other process start as PID1 and then `execve()` to dcron - it doesn't work (setpgid returns EPERM for reasons explained in [setpgid(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setpgid.2.html#ERRORS)).

**UPDATE:** See https://github.com/dubiousjim/dcron/issues/13